# How to change background colour in a carousel based on a condition

Tags: javascript, dom, carousel, background-color, owl-carousel

I would like to change the background colour of carousel elements whose price is below £500. 
I need to do it in JavaScript DOM but nothing seems to be working.... Here is what I came up with so far:

```
// Get the elements- price and each carousel element

let price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");
let greenBackground = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

//Prices are given as strings so I tried to convert it to a number to be able to compare

let priceAsNumber = parseInt(price, 10); 

//and finally I tried to apply the condition to change the background color

function changeBackground () {
  if (priceAsNumber <= 500) {
  document.greenBackground.style.background = #81CA81; 
  }
};

changeBackground();
```

I am a beginner, so the code might be missing a lot, but I would really appreciate some tips to achieve the result!

Here is a sample of html:

```
<div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 2446px;"><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 152.857px;"><li class="all-months close selected"><label class="date-price-holidays">All Holidays<input type="radio" id="filter60_24" name="filter60" value="24" data-filter="24" data-compare="== 24 &amp;&amp; r.matchFlights[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth] &gt;= jvh.search.settings.currentAirportId &amp;&amp; &#39;24&#39; == " data-no="50" data-type="groupTxt" data-pos="-1" class="noautostyle filter-active" data-name-value="month" checked="checked" data-no-remember-notification="true"><span><span class="count">516</span> <span>found</span></span></label></li></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 152.857px;"><li class="close">
                                <label class="date-price-holidays">
                                    <span class="month">Mar<span class="year">2020</span></span>
                                    <input type="radio" id="filter60_2" name="filter60" value="2" data-filter=" r.matchFlights[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth] &gt;= jvh.search.settings.currentAirportId &amp;&amp; r.sale[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth]" data-compare="&gt; 0" data-no="50" data-type="groupTxt" data-pos="2" class="noautostyle" data-name-value="month" data-no-remember-notification="true">
                                    <span class="count-and-price"><span class="count">2</span> <span class="holidays">holidays</span><span class="from"> from </span><span class="price">£629<span class="pp">pp</span></span></span>
                                </label>
                            </li></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 152.857px;"><li class="close">
                                <label class="date-price-holidays">
                                    <span class="month">Apr<span class="year">2020</span></span>
                                    <input type="radio" id="filter60_3" name="filter60" value="3" data-filter=" r.matchFlights[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth] &gt;= jvh.search.settings.currentAirportId &amp;&amp; r.sale[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth]" data-compare="&gt; 0" data-no="50" data-type="groupTxt" data-pos="3" class="noautostyle" data-name-value="month" data-no-remember-notification="true">
                                    <span class="count-and-price"><span class="count">105</span> <span class="holidays">holidays</span><span class="from"> from </span><span class="price">£249<span class="pp">pp</span></span></span>
                                </label>
                            </li></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 152.857px;"><li class="close">
                                <label class="date-price-holidays">
                                    <span class="month">May<span class="year">2020</span></span>
                                    <input type="radio" id="filter60_4" name="filter60" value="4" data-filter=" r.matchFlights[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth] &gt;= jvh.search.settings.currentAirportId &amp;&amp; r.sale[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth]" data-compare="&gt; 0" data-no="50" data-type="groupTxt" data-pos="4" class="noautostyle" data-name-value="month" data-no-remember-notification="true">
                                    <span class="count-and-price"><span class="count">450</span> <span class="holidays">holidays</span><span class="from"> from </span><span class="price">£289<span class="pp">pp</span></span></span>
                                </label>
                            </li></div><div class="owl-item active" style="width: 152.857px;"><li class="close">
                                <label class="date-price-holidays">
                                    <span class="month">Jun<span class="year">2020</span></span>
                                    <input type="radio" id="filter60_5" name="filter60" value="5" data-filter=" r.matchFlights[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth] &gt;= jvh.search.settings.currentAirportId &amp;&amp; r.sale[jvh.search.settings.currentMonth]" data-compare="&gt; 0" data-no="50" data-type="groupTxt" data-pos="5" class="noautostyle" data-name-value="month" data-no-remember-notification="true">
                                    <span class="count-and-price"><span class="count">402</span> <span class="holidays">holidays</span><span class="from"> from </span><span class="price">£559<span class="pp">pp</span></span></span>
                                </label>
```

Comment: Can you include ```HTML``` code in the question as well??

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example so we can see the current outputs or provide an explanation with any errors

Comment: `let price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");` are you getting element or    Price with this

Comment: I am trying to do it for this website https://www.jamesvillas.co.uk/search-results?nights=7&adults=2&children=0&airport=LGW,MAN,BHX,GLA&country=14&flex=3&width=1903

Would this help?

Comment: `let price = document.getElementsByClassName("price")` by this you get array of elements. you need to loop and get innertext and then do `parseInt()`

Comment: I was trying to get the price

Comment: _“Prices are given as strings so I tried to convert it to a number to be able to compare”_ - `parseInt` is not able to parse a value like '£289' into a number, that will only get you `NaN` (Not a Number). You need to remove the pound sign from this first of all.

Comment: (Owl carousel uses jQuery anyway, so it might perhaps be a bit easier to get the necessary looping over the elements done in jQuery rather than vanilla JS, if you are familiar with jQuery syntax …)

Comment: I am not familiar with JQuery yet, is it possible to do it with Vanilla JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `let price = document.getElementsByClassName("price");` you'll receive a HTMLCollection object.

My recommendation: if you want to get only one element just to use `querySelector`
like below:

```
let price = document.querySelector('.price');
let greenBackground = document.getElementsByClassName('.close');
```

So here you're receiving DOM Element Object. 
Then you should get it's value firstly and then to parse it.

```
let priceAsNumber = parseInt(price.innerText, 10);
```

So, whole solution should look like next:

```
let price = document.querySelector('.price');
let greenBackground = document.getElementsByClassName('.close');
let priceAsNumber = parseInt(price.innerText, 10);
function changeBackground () {
  if (priceAsNumber <= 500) {
     document.greenBackground.style.background = #81CA81; 
  }
};
changeBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is quick example of working code and example on plunker

```
<script>
  function changeColor(){
    // get all price nodes
    let priceNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('price');

    //iteration over all collected HTMLnodes
    for(let i = 0; i< priceNodes.length; i++){
      //parse the value and remove euro sign
      let nodeWithPrice = priceNodes[i].textContent.slice(1);

      //convert string value to numeric
      nodeWithPrice = parseInt(nodeWithPrice);

      //check according your condition
      if(nodeWithPrice <= 500){

        //if price less or equal of 500 - change color of html-node
        //find your node using Element.closest() method
        console.log(priceNodes[i].closest('.close'));
        priceNodes[i].closest('.close').style.background = '#81CA81';
      }
    }
  }

  changeColor();
</script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Ln9YXuAowbeWCKJ9Ifzt?p=info